How can I create an inexpensive glossy finish to the back of my acoustic guitar?
I have an entry level acoustic guitar with a matte finish.  I have a guitar lift that I want to use with it to play, but had to purchase these 3M glossy foils that I can stick to the back of the guitar so the suction cups stick to it.  The problem is that with the small foils, it seems there isn't enough glossy surface area on the back of the guitar to keep the suction cups from slipping off.  I notice sometimes after the guitar lift suction cup falls off that it's pulled the center of the foil away from the guitar itself - I have to press it back onto the wood and push the air pockets out.

I can't justify the cost to have a Luthier lacquer this guitar just so that I can keep the guitar lift from slipping off.  Are there any other options to create a glossy finish on the whole back of the guitar so that guitar lift sticks without dropping a lot of money into it?  Possibly something like the 3M foil material, but a much larger single sheet to stick to the entire back of the guitar and cut to fit?
Thanks

Before touching the guitar, I'd try putting a finish onto a scrap of maple ply just to see if I could achieve something that works!

I'd consider flatting the whole back with sandpaper, then spraying lacquer over the lot, giving a smoother surface, with no ripples, which are where the air is leaking in.
Never heard of these lifts, it's amazing to find something you maybe don't need, but if they work for you, good luck!

I agree with Tim.
Sanding smooth, then applying lacquer to create a flat, glossy surface.
One note;
I have never used a guitar lift device, because I always perform while standing up, with the guitar strapped on. But I can see where a seated Classical guitar player would find some utility in such a thing.
I do have a similar item mounted to my elderly Ovation Balladeer, and it is called the 'Standing Ovation'. It's simply there to keep the guitar from rolling up on you because of the rounded bowl back shape.  It is mounted with sticky-backed Velcro, and it's brilliant.

For wood that has pores like this, you really need grain filler under the lacquer to get a flat surface. Sanding it down will just expose new pores as you go.

Thanks everyone - will give this a try and report back if it works.  I just ordered MINWAX Clear Aerosol Lacquer - which looked inexpensive and others have reported using it for wood instruments with positive results.

What grit sand paper should I use before applying any lacquer?

240 wet........
